# Issues writing data back to json from php

Tags: php, json

I'm having a weird time writing data back to JSON from a PHP app.  What I'm not getting is the same exact code (minus obvious naming modifications) works just fine in another app without issue, however in this one specifically, it's just not accepting it.  Sample code is as follows -

```
<?php

$title = 'Dinner Randomizer 9000';

?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
<?php

$jsonRand = file_get_contents('dinner.json');
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonRand, true);
$dinner = $jsonArray[rand(0, count($jsonArray) -1)];
$dinnerString = json_encode($dinner);

if (($pos = strpos($dinnerString, ":")) !== FALSE) {
    $dinner2 = substr($dinnerString, $pos+1);
}

$result = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -]/s','', $dinner2);

?> 

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Dinner is <strong><?php echo $result; ?></strong>

<br />
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
That doesn't sound good, <a class="alert-link" href="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">try again.</a>
</div>
</div>
<div>
    <?php
    $message = '';
    $error = '';

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["title"]))
        {
            $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter dinner item</label>";
        }
        else{
            if(file_exists('dinner.json'))
            {
                $current_data = file_get_contents('dinner.json');
                $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
                $extra = array(
                    'title' =>  $_POST['title']
                );
                $array_data[] = $extra;
                $final_data = json_encode($arraydata);
                if(file_put_contents('dinner.json', $final_data))
                {
                    $message = "<label class='text-success'>Dinner idea added.</p>";
                }
                else{
                    $error = "JSON file does not exist";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <h3 align=""> Add a dinner idea</h3><br />
    <form method="post">
        <?php
        if(isset($error))
        {
            echo $error;

        }
        ?>
        <br />
        <label>Dinner idea</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info" /><br />
        <?php
        if(isset($message))
        {
            echo $message;
        }
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

On the WORKING app, it will append the JSON data no problem and the data shows in the fullCalendar jQuery app.  However this is just a basic dinner randomizer I wrote using similar code (admittedly while drinking) to help me lazily pick dinner options, yet it's just inserting `null` into the JSON for some reason when I submit the data.  I've tried a bunch of different "fixes" with no luck and I'm sure it's something stupid and I'll regret asking StackOverflow for help lol.  But yeah...at this point, I'm lost - the JSON isn't complex either....

```
[
    {
        "title": "Chicken cordon bleu"
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: So, what **exactly** is not running? What have you tried to debug this problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase - I missed an underscore.  This is why I shouldn't drink and attempt to code something...and it won't let me delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array_data[] = $extra;
$final_data = json_encode($arraydata);
```

You're missing an underscore on the second line.

Comment: Wow lol - thank you for pointing out my fail.  I can't believe it was THAT easy haha.  Fixing the _ worked perfectly and everything functions fine now.  Thank you...I knew it was going to be something stupid haha.

Comment: … and that’s why you should enable proper PHP error reporting during development, so that PHP has a chance to alert you to such mistakes.